# converting oracle trigger to sql server trigger

Tags: sql-server-2012

I'm little confused converting the oracle trigger to sql server. Any pointers is highly appreciated. I'm not sure how to replace "if inserting then" and "if updating then" in sql server ?

```
  create or replace trigger tg_ap
  before insert or update of strno, strfac, strfacstreet, strfacstreet2
  on AP
  for each row 
  begin 
  if inserting then
  :new.I_stat_ind:= 'Insert';
  end if;
   if updating then
      :new.I_stat_ind:= 'Update';
   end if;
   END;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQLServer makes it a bit tricky when it comes to detecting if the operation is an Update, Insert or Delete.

I will not write your Trigger, but here is some code that should help you to find out the current operation:

```
Create Trigger [name] on [table] Before Insert, Update As
Begin
declare @actionId int    


select @actionId = case
                       when i.id is not null and d.id is     null then 1 -- insert
                       when i.id is not null and d.id is not null then 2 -- update
                       when i.id is     null and d.id is not null then 3 -- delete
                     end          
  from      inserted i full join deleted  d on d.id = i.id

Your Code goes here
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I assume I should use Instead of Insert, Update ? As I realized there is no before Insert, Update in sql server ?

Comment: You are right. There is no such thing as Before on MSSQL-Server. I dont know what you want to achieve, but AFTER is in most cases a suiting alternative